# docker-Java stop timeout

Tags: docker, docker-java

i'm using the java-docker client from here: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java.
I trying to figure out how to set the stop timeout for the docker stop command.

So i'm using in java the method `dockerClient.stopContainerCmd(containerId)).exec();` but there is no option for the stop timeout, like the docker cli provides. Maybe someone has already solved the problem or has an idea ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`dockerClient.stopContainerCmd()`](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docker-java-api/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/DockerClient.java#L229) returns a [`StopContainerCmd`](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docker-java-api/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/StopContainerCmd.java) object, and that has a [`.withTimeout()`](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docker-java-api/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/StopContainerCmd.java#L28) method.  You should be able to add this into your call chain:

```java
dockerClient
  .stopContainerCmd(containerId)
  .withTimeout(new Integer(60)) // appears to be seconds
  .exec();
```

Comment: nice i didn't see this, i'll check this out